# VB.NET - Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to load a Gridview using VB.NET, but I am receiving the message below when I execute the Linq query.  I'm executing a stored procedure.  I check the SP on SQL Server and it is returning results, but I can't get VB.Net to accept the results.  I very new to Linq and Entity Framework.  Any help would be appreciated.

> Message=Unable to cast object of type '`WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2[`WindowsApplication1.uspGetAll_Result`,WindowsApplication1.uspGetAll_Result`]' to type '`System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WindowsApplication1.uspGetAll_Result`]'.

Here is the code.

```
    'Using Linq to Entities
    Dim CatFNQuery As IQueryable(Of uspGetAll_Result)

    CatFNQuery = From x In fanDbContext.uspGetAll(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing) _
                 Select x

    'MsgBox(CatFNQuery.Count)
    If CatFNQuery Is Nothing Then
        '
    Else
        gvResults.DataSource = CatFNQuery
    End If
```

Its failing on the CATFNQUERY = ... line.

Comment: I tried to change iQueryable to iEnumerable.  It got past the error.  I have 3000 records returned.  But the gridview will not load the data in gvResults.DataSource = CATFNQuery line.

Comment: I got it to work.  I change it to iEnumerable and changed the following line: CatFNQuery = (From x In fanDbContext.uspGetAll(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing) _
                 Select x).ToList

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the datasource has to be of the following types for it to be able to bind to it.

> The DataGridView class supports the standard Windows Forms data-binding model. This means the data source can be of any type that implements one of the following interfaces:
>   The IList interface, including one-dimensional arrays.
>   The IListSource interface, such as the DataTable and DataSet classes.
>   The IBindingList interface, such as the BindingList(Of T) class.
>   The IBindingListView interface, such as the BindingSource class.

What you have there is an [IQueryable(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Which inherits from IEnumerable and thus does not implement any of the interfaces stated above.

Casting it to a List(Of T) with .ToList would solve the problem as you state in your comment.

```
gvResults.DataSource = CatFNQuery.ToList()
```

Maybe you could even try a Bindingsource.

```
Dim bindingSource as New BindingSource()
bindingSource.DataSource = CatFNQuery
gvResults.DataSource = bindingsource
```

Since a [datasource for a bindingsource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) supports many more types.